# ediFabric 6.7.7 - validation of generic EDI message

Tags: c#, edi, edifabric

I am using new updated ediFabric 6.7.7 and i am trying to validate generic message - so i can not cast it to particular class of particular version.

I have an issue with xml serialization.

This code works (it is pretty similar to code in ediFabric unit tests)

```
var invoice = (M_810) msg.Value;
var validation  = new List<string>(invoice.ValidateX12(xsdStream));
```

but this throws an exception

```
var validation  = new List<string>(msg.Value.ValidateX12(xsdStream));
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   EdiFabric.Rules.X12004010810.M_810 was not expected. Use the
>   XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not
>   known statically

So my question is - is it somehow possible to validate generic message, w\o explicitly casting it to particular class.

The way i am getting correct schema here is via GS Header and ST01 via reflection.

Of course i can write my own Xml Serializer and vaildate against Xsd schema using `XsdSchemaCollection`, but `EdiMessage<S_ISA, S_GS>` contains `ValidateX12()` method and i want to use it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now available in version 6.8.2. You can call it like:
var validation = new List(msg.Value.Validate());

It now resolves internally the xsd and the format.

Comment: Thanks, I will try